# What to do with questions which are no longer relevant

Tags: discussion, obsolete-information

I bumped onto [this one question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5543/), and I doubt it can be salvaged by being updated or having [a warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92611/) attached. I think it should simply be deleted.

Title of the question was: *How to install Iceweasel 4 in Debian 6 (Squeeze)*.

Comment: Without further comment, nobody knows what the content of that question was and why it was deleted. So you should delete this question here too - it's useless now. Or maybe add a description of that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bumped into your own question? It's deleted now; in the future you can save yourself some time and just [flag for mod attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review)

Comment: I noticed it because someone upvoted it recently. I asked just in case someone found it worthy.